# Remove possible object relationships within pictures? Trying to xlCopy with memory restrictions

Tags: excel, memory, copy-paste, vba

I have a program that copies the cells and overlaying map. The area that is being copied has color gradient conditionals, lots of data, and overlapping picture objects. using the code:

```
range.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

Using xlPicture has caused the code to not be able to paste and have all sorts of excel errors such as memory and resources limits hit.

```
range.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```

XlBitmap on the other hand removes this error.

I understand having that many entities to copy is taxing. Does the screenshot take into account the object natures within the range of capture? if so is there a way to reduce the load or remove that calculation?